# SATA3 (P67 Chipset) VS GSATA3 (Marvell 88SE9128)?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, ssd, sata

I just bought a Gigabyte P67-UD7-B3 and it came with support for SATA2 SATA3 and GSATA3.

I have 1 SSD, and 1 HDD. I don't know which SATA I should connect them to. I don't wish to make a RAID because I think it will slow down the SSD.

OCZ Vertex 3 -

SATA3 (P67)

or

GSATA (Marvell 88SE9128)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not interested in making a RAID, then I'd suggest considering connecting one drive to the Intel-based SATA3, and the other to a GSATA port.

Since the main (only?) difference between SATA and "GSATA" is that "GSATA" uses a separate on-board controller (the Marvell; separate from the Intel chipset).

This is why I suggest using one of each, as it will give each drive it's own controller, data path, etc.

On the OTHER hand, turning off one of the controllers (ie: the GSATA one) may free up enough resources that having both drives on a single controller may be the 'speedier' option.

Personally, I'd turn off the Marvell and just go with the Intel for both drives, one less driver to care about.